# How to handle BadRequestBodyException and ResouceNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new in java world. In service layer i have this `updateCustomer` method.

Am i handling exceptions correctly?
Is there a better way to do it?
Any pros and cons with my way of doing it?

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateCustomer(String id, Customer customer) throws ResourceNotFoundException, BadRequestBodyException {
        log.info("Updating customer.");

        if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerName())
                && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerType())){

            Customer existingCustomer =  customerRepository.findCustomerById(id)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Error: Customer not found for id - " + id));

            existingCustomer.setCustomerName(customer.getCustomerName());
            existingCustomer.setCustomerType(customer.getCustomerType());

            customerRepository.save(existingCustomer);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Customer updated successfully.");
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestBodyException("Error: request body can not be null or empty!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here.

1. I would recommend the service layer not to return the `ResponseEntity<T>` object instead it should return the DTO or just string in your case.
2. Also for request body validation use @Valid annotation on the request body model in controller or if you want to handle the validation do that in controller not in service.
3. The controller class should be responsible for to convert/create the `ResponseEntity<?>` which sends to server.
4. In your controller class you can define the method with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation and specify how you would handle that request. Alternative to that if the exception you are handling is thrown from diffrent services then you can define the class with `@ControllerAdvice` and specify the exception handling methods there.

With regards to your code you should do the following:

```
//Controller
@Override
public ResponseEntity<String> updateCustomer(String id, Customer customer)
throws ResourceNotFoundException, BadRequestBodyException {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerName())
        || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerType())) {
        throw new BadRequestBodyException("Error: request body can not be null or empty!");
    }
    log.info("Updating customer.");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.updateCustomer(id, customer);
}

// The below exception handling method can be part of your controller or you can centralise them 
// in class annotated with ControllerAdvice 
@ExceptionHandler(BadRequestBodyException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequestBodyException(BadRequestBodyException ex) {
    var response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("status", "failure");
    response.put("message", "Request body Validation failed.");
    response.put("detailMessage", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(response);
}

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handle(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    var response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("status", "failure");
    response.put("message", "Resource not found.");
    response.put("detailMessage", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(response);
}


//Service
@Override
public String updateCustomer(String id, Customer customer) throws ResourceNotFoundException, BadRequestBodyException {
    log.info("Updating customer.");
    Customer existingCustomer = customerRepository
            .findCustomerById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Error: Customer not found for id - " + id));
    existingCustomer.setCustomerName(customer.getCustomerName());
    existingCustomer.setCustomerType(customer.getCustomerType());
    customerRepository.save(existingCustomer);
    return "Customer updated successfully.";
}
```

Hope this helps!